# How to add fonts to windows servercore 2019 with IIS

Tags: windows, docker, iis, dockerfile

I'm trying to host a http to pdf web solution in windows servercore 2019 container with IIS.
The problem is that windows servercore 2019 container only has one font.
I searched and tried to add fonts to the container. It worked fine.

However, my solution is behind IIS, and IIS doesn't seem to pickup the new fonts. How do I let IIS pickup new fonts in windows\fonts folder?

I read somewhere that I have to restart IIS to pickup font changes? But I can't restart IIS in windows servercore container, right? It's entry point is server monitor that monitors IIS.

The Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

# base Image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
COPY dotnet-hosting-6.0.1-win.exe .
RUN ./dotnet-hosting-6.0.1-win.exe /quiet /install
# Install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013
COPY vcredist_x64.exe .
RUN ./vcredist_x64.exe /passive
# Add fonts to the image
COPY Fonts/* /Windows/Fonts/

COPY FontReg.exe .
RUN ./FontReg.exe

# Configure web servers to bind to port 80 when present
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 `
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
    
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

====== SKIP SOLUTION BUILD ======

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

Comment: What is `FontReg.exe`? And why not use PowerShell directly? https://mickitblog.blogspot.com/2021/06/powershell-install-fonts.html

Comment: @LexLi it's from http://code.kliu.org/misc/fontreg/, it seems to be working because I ran "Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" and the fonts I want to install are listed. But I will try to use powershell to install.

Comment: Why you cannot restart IIS in windows servercore container? You can use command line `iisreset /noforce` to restart IIS directly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The idea is to get a clean servercore 2019 image, install fonts first, and then enable IIS. It'll pickup all the installed fonts.